# Prove that $i\hbar\dot{\hat{\Omega}}=[\hat{\Omega},\hat{H}]$ , where $\hat{\Omega}(\hat{x},\hat{p})$ is Taylor expandable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

How do I show that $i\hbar\dot{\hat{\Omega}}=[\hat{\Omega},\hat{H}]$ , where $\hat{\Omega}(\hat{x},\hat{p})$ is Taylor expandable, $\hat{H}(\hat{x},\hat{p})$ is the Hamiltonian of the system and $\hat{x}, \hat{p}$ are the positional and momentum operators respectively.

I have already proved that $i\hbar\dot{\hat{x}}=[\hat{x},\hat{H}]$ and $i\hbar\dot{\hat{p}}=[\hat{p},\hat{H}]$ and also the classical analogue using Poisson bracket that $\dot{\Omega}=\{\Omega, H\}_{PB}$. I am stuck after this point, and have no clue how to proceed with the question.

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to prove this *from*? Are you starting from the Schrödinger picture? How did you "prove" $\mathrm{i}\hbar\dot{x} = [x,H]$?

Comment: Hi HelloWorld1729. Welcome to Phys.SE. What is your definition of Taylor expandable for non-commuting operators?

Comment: @Qmechanic Well, our instructor told us that by "taylor expandable" he meant "Well-behaving" operators. Any non-rigorous proof should work ig.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Well I showed that $[\hat{x}, \hat{G}]=i\hbar\frac{\partial \hat{G}}{\partial \hat{p}}$ for all taylor expandable $\hat{G}(\hat{p})$ using $\hat{x}=i\hbar\frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{p}}$. Then I just used the quantum analogue of the classical result that  $\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}=\dot{x}$.

Comment: But if you're allowed to use "quantum analogues", why are you not allowed to just say this is the "quantum analogue" of $\dot{\Omega} = \{\Omega,H\}$ and skip this confusing argumentation in the first place? This exercise doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @ACuriousMind the motive of the exercise was to show us the quantum and classical correspondence between Poisson Brackets and Commutators., and the only analogue which I used to work up from was that pair of Hamilton's classical equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you mentioned that you already have $i\hbar\dot{x}=[x,H]$ and $i\hbar\dot{p}=[p,H]$  (I am omitting the hats above the operators for convinience). Now there exists a "product rule" for the commutator, with which I mean that for Operators $A_1,A_2,H$ we have $[A_1A_2,H]=A_1[A_2,H]+[A_1,H]A_2$ which you can see by just writing out the commutators. This can of course be extended to arbitrary products by induction: $[\prod_{k=1}^{n}A_n,H]=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}A_j )[A_k,H] (\prod_{l=k+1}^{n}A_l)$ where the "empty product" is supposed to just be the identity, i.e. for example $\prod_{j=1}^{0}A_j=1$. The proof by induction is not very difficult. You can also see the sum as a telescoping sum when you write the commutator in the middle as a difference and obtain the result.

Well, now look at the terms in the Taylor expansion of $\Omega$: They are of the form $x^np^m$ with constants in front. This is just a product of $n+m$ operators so we can use our "product rule": $[x^np^m,H]=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}x^j )[x,H] (\prod_{l=k+1}^{n}x^l)p^m+x^n\sum_{k=1}^{m}(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}p^j )[p,H] (\prod_{l=k+1}^{m}p^l)$. Here we have two sums because I split the product first in the factors $x^n$ and $p^m$ before applying the rule.

Okay, we are almost finished. Just plug in $i\hbar\dot{x}=[x,H]$ and $i\hbar\dot{p}=[p,H]$ for the commutators and then use the product rule of the time derivative "backwards". That means: $[x^np^m,H]=i\hbar \sum_{k=1}^{n}(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}x^j )\dot{x} (\prod_{l=k+1}^{n}x^l)p^m+  i\hbar x^n\sum_{k=1}^{m}(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}p^j )\dot{p}  (\prod_{l=k+1}^{m}p^l)=i\hbar \frac{d}{dt} x^np^m$. Now we have shown the statement for one term in the Taylor expansion and because of linearity it extends to the whole Taylor series.

Hopefully that was helpful!

Comment: This argument presumes the form of the power series for $\Omega$. Since $x$ and $p$ do not commute you need to extend it to terms like $xpx...$. In this case, because the canonical commutator is a *constant*, such an extension is (formally) straightforward

Comment: @Sal This is true, thank you for adding that! I implicitely assumed that the commutator had already been used to bring the terms in the form I mentioned but it might be unclear to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a time-independent Hamiltonian $H$  (the time-dependent case works just the same, but with a heavier formalism), Heisenberg's equations of motion are solved by :
\begin{align}
x(t) = e^{-iHt/\hbar}x(0)e^{iHt/\hbar} \\
p(t) = e^{-iHt/\hbar}p(0)e^{iHt/\hbar} 
\end{align}
Then, we have :
\begin{align}
\Omega(t) &= \Omega(x(t),p(t)) \\
&= \Omega\left(e^{iHt/\hbar}x(0)e^{-iHt/\hbar},e^{iHt/\hbar}p(0)e^{-iHt/\hbar} 
\right) \\
&=e^{iHt/\hbar}\Omega(0)e^{-iHt/\hbar}
\end{align}
So, taking the time derivative, we get :
$$i\hbar\dot \Omega (t) = [\Omega,H]$$